# border radius top left on triangle using CSS

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

I have this code

```css
div {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 85px 85px 0 0;
  border-color: #c00000 transparent transparent transparent;
  float: left;
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

How can I apply border radius top left to above CSS triangle? It seem like impossible [here](http://jsfiddle.net/mhb4xfug/).

Comment: float left and position absolute?

Comment: please post your HTML code.

Comment: why downvote.. question is really nice +1

Answer (score 15, accepted):

- First set equal `border-width` on all the sides
- Then add `border-color` to `top` and `left` and set `right` and `bottom` `transparent`

```css
div {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 55px;
  border-color: #c00000 transparent transparent #c00000;
  float: left;
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
  border-radius: 10px 0px 0px 0px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

with `box-shadow` you can use a pseudo element for giving a `box-shadow`

```css
div {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 55px;
  border-color: #c00000 transparent transparent #c00000;
  float: left;
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
  border-radius: 10px 0px 0px 0px;
}
div:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 1px;
  height: 155px;
  top: -55px;
  left: 54px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform-origin: left top;
  box-shadow: 2px 1px 6px 1px red;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: can this be apply to box-shadow as well?

Comment: box shadow at the bottom right, u know what is box shadow right?

Comment: added example with `box-shadow` @JohnSt

Answer (score 8):

Wrap it inside a parent div and give the parent `border`

http://jsfiddle.net/o6y997ds/

```
<div class="parent"><div class="div"></div></div>
.parent{
        border-radius:10px 0px 0px 0px;  
        overflow:hidden; 
       }
```

Comment: @chipChocolate.py.. nice!